# Variable not doing what it's supposed to?

Tags: java

I'm doing homework from CSE 142 assigned  by my tutor, I am trying to replicate the code but the size variable is not changing the size of the squares drawn by the program, it is instead changing the distances from each square to another square. I don't know where to start looking to fix this problem, so maybe you guys could help with that a little bit

```
   import java.awt.*;
   public class CafeWall{
   public static final int WIDTH = 800;
   public static final int HEIGHT = 450;   

   public static void main (String[] args){
      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
      panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      grid(g, 250, 200, 6, 25, 6, 10, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK);
      grid(g, 10, 150, 8, 25, 8, 0, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
      grid(g, 425, 180, 9, 20, 10, 10, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
      grid(g, 400, 20, 4, 35, 4, 35, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
      singleRow(g, 0, 0, 8, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, 25);
      singleRow(g, 50, 70, 10, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, 25);

   }
   public static void grid(Graphics g, int x, int y, int row, int size, 
int column, int offset,Color color1, Color color2){

      for(int i = 0; i < row;i++){
         int offsetTemp = 0;
         offsetTemp = offset;
          singleRow(g, x + offsetTemp, y+size*i, column, color1, color2, 
          size);
          if(i % 2 != 0){
          offsetTemp = offset;



          singleRow(g, x, y+size*i, column, color1, color2, size);
         }
      }
  }

   public static void singleRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int num, Color 
   color1, Color color2, int size){
      for(int i = 0; i < num ; i++){
         if (i % 2 == 0){
         square(g , x+size*i, y, 25, Color.BLACK, true);

         } else {
         square(g , x+size*i, y, 25, Color.WHITE, false);
         }        
      }
   }
   public static void square(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size, Color 
color, boolean diagonals){
      g.setColor(color);
      g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
      if (diagonals){
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.drawLine(x,y,x+size,y+size);
         g.drawLine(x+size,y,x,y+size);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW this is using DrawingPanel from Marty Stepp and Stuart Reges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your two lines

```
square(g , x+size*i, y, 25, Color.BLACK, true);
```

and

```
square(g , x+size*i, y, 25, Color.WHITE, false);
```

you're passing `25` as the value or the parameter of `square` called `size`.  So all your squares will be size `25`.  Maybe instead of `25`, you want to pass your variable `size` as the value of this parameter.  Like

```
square(g , x+size*i, y, size, Color.BLACK, true);
```